# How to set Default SMS prompt for KitKat

Tags: android, message, android-4.4-kitkat

I have created an SMS application that shows all the messages properly and also a `BroadcastReceiver` that helps in letting me know new messages on arrival.

Using the URI's help `content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true` I am able to retrieve the messages.

This is working fine even on KitKat. I can send SMS, read SMS but I am not able to delete the SMS because my App is not the default SMS app.

### Question:

How do I prompt user to make the App default? I looked at [this blog](http://goo.gl/kiQrsG):

I tried the code given on it but I don't see any difference? Am I missing anything here?

Here is the code:

```
 int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (currentapiVersion >= 19)
    {
        final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
        if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) 
        {
            // App is not default.
            // Show the "not currently set as the default SMS app" interface
            View viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.not_default_app);
            viewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Set up a button that allows the user to change the default SMS app
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent intent =
                            new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, 
                            myPackageName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        else 
        {
            // App is the default.
            // Hide the "not currently set as the default SMS app" interface
            View viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.not_default_app);
            viewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
```

Awaiting your response!
Thanks!

Comment: we can't throw suggestions in the air without any code to look at

Comment: As I told you I followed the steps given in the above blog.

Comment: The code seems to be good... did you put logs and see if the onClick is being called?And the above code is in an activity,right?

Comment: Yep it is in an activity and Yes. It is being called after the click.

Comment: what device are you using

Comment: That is interesting. I can only comment that you take a look at your manifest and make sure that it matches with the 4.4 requirement. And if you do find a solution to this, post it as an answer. I will look up and see if i can find something though

Comment: Can you post the manifest too? -- myPackageName string too.

Comment: can any one tell me how to make sms app default in api 10

Comment: What do you mean by SMS app default? What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved by entering the following in the manifest.

The most important part we should use everything, including MMS part if not it will not work.

```
<!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
<activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        <data android:scheme="mms" />
        <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
<service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
         android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
         android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        <data android:scheme="mms" />
        <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```