# Change the app default sms by user programatically

Tags: java, android

My goal is to display a message to the user directly allowing them to change the default application after pressing a button.
But it's doesn't work.

I tried on 2 different phones.
The first is under API 28 and the second under API 29.
My method works for the first one. I have my request to change the default application.
However I have nothing for the second

The Code :

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnreg).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnEnreg = view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnreg);

                Intent setSmsAppIntent =
                        new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                setSmsAppIntent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,
                        getActivity().getPackageName());
                startActivityForResult(setSmsAppIntent, 5);


                if (hasPermissions(getContext(),Permissions)){
                    createOnClicBtnEnreg();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Insertion Réussi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    if(!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)){
                        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS};
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),permissions,1);
                    }else{
                        lay_dataset1=view.findViewById(R.id.lay_dataset1); // On récupère l'objet graphique
                        messagePermissionObligatoire();
                    }
                }


            }


        });
    }
```

My permission requests are working fine but I have absolutely nothing for the choice of the default application.

The manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testbackup">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MenuDeroulant"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu_deroulant"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: That's now handled with `RoleManager` in the newer versions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58575173.

Comment: Thank's so much Mike !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  On purpose.  That choice must be made manually by the user.  If an app could do it, a piece of malware could take over as the default SMS app and read all their messages.  A smart one could even do so transparently.  To avoid that, an app cannot set the default SMS app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm just trying to get the user to get a window that asks him if he wants to change this parameter.